# What is the mechanism in CPython for invoking a Python function from C code?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, cpython

Suppose I am writing a CPython C extension, and inside it I want to call some function written in Python.

The internet suggests it involves calling `PyObject *PyObject_Call()` from the C extension. Is that so?

If it is, I would like to understand the mechanism involved inside the VM for invoking the called Python function. I have spent time going through the source code of `PyObject *PyObject_Call()`, but was unable to fully grasp what is going on, so guidance will be appreciated.

Which one of the following is true?

1. The VM pushes a new stack frame, etc. - but then waits for *the next eval loop iteration* to naturally switch control to the called Python function
2. The VM invokes a *new bytecode interpretation loop* in order to interpret the called function immediately
3. Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 2. This is also the same mechanism used to call Python functions from within Python code. One instance of the bytecode evaluation loop is used for each Python stack frame, and the evaluation loop is reentrant.

`PyObject_Call` is an appropriate function to use. (There are others, which may sometimes be more convenient, but `PyObject_Call` is general-purpose.) You may have had trouble understanding what it does because it's just a dispatcher. It delegates to the called object's implementation of the function call operator.

For ordinary Python function objects, you can find that as [`function_call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/funcobject.c#L625) in `Objects/funcobject.c`, and you can trace the calls down through [`_PyFunction_FastCallDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/call.c#L298) and eventually down to [`PyEval_EvalFrameEx`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Python/ceval.c#L737). That calls `interp->eval_frame`, which [defaults](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Python/pystate.c#L211) to [`_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Python/ceval.c#L744), which contains the bytecode evaluation loop.

Comment: I highly appreciate the detailed answer, especially the links to the actual source code. Very helpful, thank you!
Question just to affirm my understanding: does this mean that in the running CPython process, for every Python-level stackframe, there is always a corresponding native C-Level stackframe?

Comment: @AvivCohn: Yes. (There are also a large number of C stack frames that don't correspond to Python stack frames.)

Comment: Very interesting, I never knew that. I wonder how it's done in other language implementations, will go do some research. Anyway, thanks a lot! :)